# i am trying to run android project in android studio but its emulator is not working showing this error:

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

When I'm trying to run Android Project in Android Studio,

The Emulator is not working and It is showing this error:

```
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Size: 69206016
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Block size: 4096
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Blocks per group: 32768
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inodes per group: 4224
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inode size: 256
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Journal blocks: 1024
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Label: 
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using    software renderer.
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your  environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
emulator: device fd:540
Could not initialize emulated framebufferHAX is not working and    emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Another virtual device with it's default RAM Settings.. And try to use CPU type arm... I hope this helps you..